# Why does the Atmosphere Harvester only sometimes store the element?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I have multiple [Atmoshpere Harvesters](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Atmosphere_Harvester) on several planets. As long as I am on the same planet they harvest as expected.

What could be the reason that these Harvesters don't store the harvested elements during my absence (using the Teleporter or my Ship)? Sometimes I can clear them after my return with the full 250 pieces of elements. Most of the time, they are just empty. I'm sure that I have refilled the fuel source before I left the planet.

Does it matter which fuel source I charge? Or does it make a difference which element I try to harvest? Or is the duration of my absence relevant?

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same behavior (Beyond update on PC).

I do not know if it is by design or a bug, but if I leave the planet or base, either via starship or teleporter, anything in atmospheric collectors, oxygen collectors, portable mineral extractors or refiners gets emptied out.

You will see similar behavior from refiners on your freighters if you warp to another system.

Update Nov2022: In more recent updates, this behavior may have changed. I have noticed that refined product stays in the refiners when it would have otherwise disappeared (warped, left the planet, logged out and back in).